# GWT Widget Blur focus

Tags: java, gwt, blur, onblur

I have 2 widgets

1. TextBox
2. FocusPanel

> ```
> TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
> textBox.addBlurHandler(event -> Window.alert("Hello world"));
> ```

How to do. If the TextBox loses focus (click anywhere in the project), alert **Hello World** appears. BUT If you click on the FocusPanel, an only alert **Hello FocusPanel** appears

Comment: I could not reproduce this behavior. Check if there are errors in the browser's console that could block the `Hello World` alert. Also try to provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Put the alert statement inside if condition that satisfies event.source is not Focus Panel.